# Trying to scrape using HTMLSession, it is working fine, but cannot scrape full page

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to scrape top 10 news from a news article, after writing the code with the help of some tutorials, the code is running fine but I am able to print only the first H4 tag. My project requires to atleast print 10. Is there any other option?

I wanted to print 10 news, but I am able print only 1.

code:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()

url= "https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/#nlatest"

r= session.get(url)
r.html.render(sleep=4, scrolldown=5)

articles = r.html.find('ul')
#print(articles)

for item in articles:
    try:
        news=item.find('h4', first=True)
        newsarticle ={}
        title = news.text
        print(title)
    except:
        pass
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

change `ui` to `li` , if you inspect the html structure of the webpage, the `li` tag is the one listing the articles. `ul` is just the parent in this case

```
articles = r.html.find('li')

for item in articles:
    try:
        news=item.find('h4', first=True)
        newsarticle ={}
        title = news.text
        print(title)
    except:
        pass


#output
#CISA warns of Zimbra bug exploited in attacks against NATO countries
#US seizes $112 million from cryptocurrency investment scammers
#WinRAR SFX archives can run PowerShell without being detected
#Cryptocurrency companies backdoored in 3CX supply chain attack
#...
```